# Images not being shown in sent emails

Tags: django, image, email, sendgrid

I am developing a site using django, and I plan on sending notifications via email. In the emails, I have a a few images such as logo etc.

For emails, I am using smtp with sendgrid.

In the email template, I have the full image src:

```
<img src="https:www.mysite.com/static/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo">
```

when I copy and paste the src in the browser, I see the image.

However, in both gmail and outlook, the image is not there. It looks like they are caching it, and using their own version of the image, but it's not there.

Comment: The URL is incorrect, it is `https://...`

Comment: That solved it... I guess when I was pasting into my browser it was automatically adding the missing double slash.

Answer (score 1):

Your **URL** is incorrect please write valid url. 
You can check own **url** on browser.

URL looks like https://www.facebook.com. but You are not using **//** before **www**

Answer (score 1):

Your url is incorrect. The reason behind it's working in the browser, the requested url without "//" after http: is rewritten to "http://".

For example I have put following url in browser's address bar,

https:github.com/

Ater the page is rendered in browser the url changed as follows

https://github.com/